# getjson alternative method for variable

Tags: jquery, json

I made a script which gets the data from a json file and parse it. It worked on a webserver.

But now I have to find a solution to get it work on a local file (`file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/script/index.html`) instead on a server. It only works in FF:

```
$.getJSON('data2.json', function(data) {   
    $.each(data.selection_form.entities, function(i,name){
        ...do something
     });
});
```

Any ideas? A local webserver is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can force jQuery to load the file via [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) by specifying a dataType of "jsonp" for the `$.ajax()` function. That will make your browser create a `<script>` tag to load the file, rather than relying on an XmlHttpRequest.  You'll need to wrap the data in a callback function, however.

*Note:* While you could use `$.getJSON(..)` to load your data via JSONP, you cannot specify the callback function explicitly (which is needed for loading a static file, as jQuery uses changing callback function names).

Your code:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: 'data2.json', 
    dataType: 'jsonp', 
    jsonpCallback: 'mycallback', 
    jsonp: false,
    success: function(data){
        $.each(data.selection_form.entities, function(i, name) {
            ... do something
        }
    }
});
```

Notice `jsonpCallback: 'mycallback'` here, we'll wrap the data from the original data2.json file in a call to a function called `mycallback`:

```
mycallback({ /* your data */ });
```

Comment: chrome gives this erormessage:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/script/data2.json?callback=mycallback. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: no, i get this:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/script/data2.json?_=1350336720429. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: another solution would be to embed the json code in a variable in the same script. But I didn't find a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Here's another alternative.

We can build out JSONP ourselves, for a one-off solution:

```
function mycallback(data){
    $.each(data.selection_form.entities, function(i,name){
        ...do something
    }
}

$('body').append('<script src="data2.json" type="text/javascript"></script">');
```

This is, essentially, how jQuery does it - but a whole lot less sophisticated.

Comment: Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/script/data2.json". index.html:52
Uncaught ReferenceError: mycallback is not defined 
the " at </script> I think is wrong.